# Rails 2 NoMethodError in BrandsController#show undefined method `order' for #<Array:0x7065083ffd08>

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am getting a strange error in my local and production servers...

```
 @search = Product.find(:all, :conditions => {:brand_id => @brand.id, :category_id => @category.id})
        @search.order ||= :descend_by_price
        @products = @search.all(params[:order] || :descend_by_price).paginate(:page => params[:page])
```

I am running rails 2.3.11 and Ruby 1.8.7 locally and on the production server.  Any help would be very appreciated.

thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`@search` is an `array` of `Product` objects. You are calling `order` method on an array for which you are getting the error that says that the method `order` is not found for an `array` (probably order method is present only for one single `Product` but not for an array of `Products`).

Comment: Alok, thanks for the response, I think you were right.  I modified to accomodate that and the error moved on me. I moved it to work with the Products object: https://gist.github.com/1386908 .   Looking at: http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Base.html , any other ideas or recomendations?

Comment: From the gist looks like you are trying to order all the Products and then on that performing a find.(order is a class method which orders all the Products on a certain criteria i think). Why not do it the other way, perform the find and add a condition to return the results in a certain order.